# The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls'

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, .net-assembly

I am getting the following errors

```
  The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  
  The type or namespace name 'ModalPopupExtender' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  
  The type or namespace name 'Accordion' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have installed ajaxControlToolKit already and I have this in my web.config file

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"><controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls></pages>
```

My .aspx page

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"       CodeBehind="PaintBrushCanvas.aspx.cs" Inherits="VirtualClassroom.PaintBrushCanvas" %>
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Paint Brush</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #container { position: relative; overflow: auto; scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;  }
  #imageView { border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC; margin: 5px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; background-color: #FFFFFF; vertical-align: top;  }
  #imageTemp { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; margin: 5px; }
  #imageTempt { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; margin: 5px; }
</style>
<link href="../StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="CanvasUtils.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
 </script>
</head>
```

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="MPBehaviorIDOpen" 
    TargetControlID="btnPopupRender" PopupControlID="panelOpen" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="panelOpenHead" OkControlID="btnOKOpen" CancelControlID="btnCancelOpen" /> 
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" BehaviorID="MPBehaviorIDResize" 
    TargetControlID="btnPopupRender" PopupControlID="panelPageSize" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="panelPageSizeHead" OkControlID="btnPageSizeOK" CancelControlID="btnPageSizeCancel" /> 

<div>
    <asp:Button id="btnPopupRender" Height="0px" Width="0px" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<table style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top;">
            <asp:Accordion ID="MyAccordion" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" 
                                HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" 
                                FadeTransitions="true" FramesPerSecond="40" TransitionDuration="250"
                                AutoSize="None" CssClass="accordionStyle" Width="140">
             <Panes>
                <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
                  <Header>Toolbox</Header>
                  <Content>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnOpen" runat="server"  Width="40px" Height="40px"
                                   OnClientClick="ShowPopup(event,'MPBehaviorIDOpen'); return false;" ImageUrl="~/Images/open.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Open"></asp:Label><br /> <br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPageSize" runat="server"  Width="40px" Height="40px"
                                   OnClientClick="ShowPopup(event,'MPBehaviorIDResize'); return false;" ImageUrl="~/Images/paperSettings.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Page Size"></asp:Label><br /> <br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDraw" runat="server"  Width="40px" Height="40px" 
                                   OnClientClick="SelectTool('pencil'); return false;" ImageUrl="~/Images/draw.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Draw"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnText" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" 
                                   OnClientClick="SelectTool('text'); return false;" ImageUrl="~/Images/text.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Text"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnLine" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" 
                                   OnClientClick="SelectTool('line'); return false;" ImageUrl="~/Images/line.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Line"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSquare" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" 
                                   OnClientClick="SelectTool('rect'); return false;" ImageUrl="~/Images/square.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Square"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" 
                                    OnClientClick="SaveDrawings();return false;"  ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Save"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExit" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" 
                                    OnClientClick="Exit();return false;"  ImageUrl="~/Images/exit.png" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Exit"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                  </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
             </Panes>
            </asp:Accordion>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; ">
            <div id="container">
                <canvas id="imageView"></canvas> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="panelOpen" class="modalPopup" style="display:none;">
    <div id="panelOpenHead" class="popupHeader">
        <p>Choose File</p>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <p>
            <input id="fileUploadImg" type="file" accept="image/*"  />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="btnOKOpen" value="OK" onclick="UpdateCanvas(); return false;" />
            <input type="button" id="btnCancelOpen" value="Cancel" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="panelPageSize" class="modalPopup" style="display:none;">
    <div id="panelPageSizeHead" class="popupHeader">
        <p>Page Size</p>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <p>
            Enter Width: <input type="text" id="txtWidth" style="width:100px;" /> px
        </p>
        <p>
            Enter Height: <input type="text" id="txtHeight" style="width:100px;" /> px
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="btnPageSizeOK" value="OK" onclick="Resize(); return false;" />
            <input type="button" id="btnPageSizeCancel" value="Cancel" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is my web.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please    visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions"      type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
      <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBCS" connectionString="data source=.; database=xxx; integrated    security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>


 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="SelectUser.aspx" defaultUrl="SelectUser.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
    <membership>
     <providers>
       <clear />
       <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
   </membership>
   <profile>
    <providers>
    <clear />
     <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"   type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
     <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"   type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"><controls>
      <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
     <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </controls></pages>
  </system.web>
     <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
       </system.webServer>
        <assemblies>

       <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

       <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

         <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

      <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
     </assemblies>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin"        publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.4" newVersion="2.1.0.4" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
   </configuration>
```

I have goggled out to get rid of this error but I cant.Please help.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists in the namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls;

But in order to use it you have to install AJAX toolkit.

And before Using a Control from AJAX toolkit you have to reister the toolkit script manager.

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

You can to do one more thing.

1.Remove the Ajax Control tab from the toolbox.

2.Re-add the tab and right-click on the tab, Select Choose Items and browse to the AjaxControltoolkit.dll file in your own project and press OK(make sure that you are using the same version of ajax toolkit as of your C# version).

3.Clean and rebuild the solution and you are ready to go.

add these assemblies to you web.config

```
    <assemblies>

            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

</assemblies>
```

and change your tagfix to asp instead of ajaxToolkit.

I think it will help you.

Comment: I have installed AJAXControlToolkit and there is no separate package for AJAXToolkit. What must I do now?@SHIVANG RANA

Comment: if you have installed toolkit then it have to work fine. Have you register the toolkit script Manager

Comment: No it doesnt It throws me the same error .see my question where I have shown my web.config .I have registered too

Comment: you have to register script manager in the particular page in which you are using a AJAX control.

Comment: Can I include in web.config?If so how must  I?

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %> I have added this in the page where I am using ajax but still It throws me the same error @SHIVANG RANA

Comment: Add both of the codes(.aspx,aspx.cx) to your Question

Comment: I have only Script Manager in my toolbox.I don't find any ToolKitScriptManager @SHIVANG RANA

Comment: tell me the version of your C# and of your Ajax Toolkit

Comment: I have downloaded ajaxToolKit 4.5 and my Target Framework version is 4.5 @SHIVANG RANA

Comment: Add your .aspx code of the particular page to your Question. after that i can try to figure out your problem

Comment: i have added few more things to answer please go through that

Comment: I have added my web.config file too.!! It throws me other errors like "unrecognised attribuite assembly"  too when I added assemebly as above  @SHIVANG RANA

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I just removed assemblies tag and all the stuff inside it and changed the TagPrefix of the relevant .aspx page  to "asp" and it worked fine @SHIVANG RANA

Answer (score 24):

I had this problem and it turned out that this was removed in version 15.1.  See https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below#toolkitscriptmanager-removed-in-v151-use-scriptmanager