# The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using ASP.NET Webforms and adding AjaxControlToolkit in my master page and I'm getting this error:
The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is my code:

Page.Master.designer.cs:

```
 protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager ToolkitScriptManager1;
```

Page.Master(aspx page):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

web.config:

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

I've added AjaxControlToolkit.dll as a reference in my project as well. I've tried almost all the answers for similar questions but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

it was removed in version 15.1. look at this [page](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below#toolkitscriptmanager-removed-in-v151-use-scriptmanager) for more info, and have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165184/the-type-or-namespace-name-toolkitscriptmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-namespac) too

Answer (score 0):

You can download and place it in your `bin` folder and add a reference to the dlls. Depending on what AJAX Coontrol Tollkit's version your project is using you may look for an older one on Google.

This is the latest one:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/