# Ajax Control Toolkit works in Visual Studio but not on website

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 web form project that has a page that's using the AjaxControlToolkit. When I run it in Visual Studio 2017 it runs fine. However, when I publish it to a website, the page with Ajax doesn't work. The error message that's thrown on the website when I try to access this page is "The type or namespace name 'HTMLEditor' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?" I'm registering the Toolkit like so:

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor"  TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

and the error indicates that the second line is the issue (by highlighting it in red). I'm using the ScriptManager:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
```

I've tried subsituting the ToolkitScriptManager, but it's not recognized. What's weird is that this used to work. It just stopped working. The web admin swears no changes were made to the web server. I'm pulling my hair out. Any idea why this would be? The website is using .Net 4. The web server is Windows 2016 Standard Edition with IIS 10. The same failure occurs if I publish the site to a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165184/the-type-or-namespace-name-toolkitscriptmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-namespac)

Comment: No, I don't believe it does, but thank you for suggesting it.